# Color Literal for UIColor-Initalizer init(white:alpha:)

Tags: xcode, uicolor

I know the usage of the color literal in Xcode but I'm only getting the color literal for rgba colors. Can I use the color literal also for the UIColor-Initializer:

```
init(white:alpha:)
```

Did I miss something, or is this not implemented? Can I change this somehow in the color picker?

Comment: You double-click the color literal and then Other... > Color picker > Color Sliders (2nd tab) > Grayscale Slider

Comment: @Alladinian Thank you, I thought that I missed something!